# Using User Defined Function from Excel in Python

Tags: python, excel, user-defined-functions, xlwings

I am trying to use a User Defined Function from an Excel Add-in, in Python. The add-in is from the [National Volume Estimator Library](https://www.fs.usda.gov/forestmanagement/products/measurement/volume/nvel/index.php) from the USDA Forest Service and are used to calculate tree volumes amongst other things. I want to calculate volume estimates for total height volume, merchantable volume, and merchandized volume. The merchandized volume is summed from individual log sorts; pulp, bolt, and sawlog.

The raw equations that I am trying to use are not publicly available because "due to the complexity and rigorous implementation process of many of the volume estimators, they cannot be easily added to a spreadsheet or simple program designed to calculate the volume of one or more trees."

The Forest Service provides Excel Volume Functions as add-ins and a DLL. Their support for the DLL in Python is outdated and currently not usable.

I haven't found much on how to pull a function from Excel and use it in Python.

Is there a way to call a user defined function from Excel and use it within Python applying it to a Pandas Dataframe?

Here is an example of what I want to do. As a proof of concept, it works, now I just need to automate it within Python.

[Excel Proof of Concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wchdX.png)

I've tried using xlwings and pyxll and haven't found any documentation on how to take an equation from excel and use it in Python. Only from python and to excel.

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using Spyder 5.4.3 and Pythong 3.11.3

Comment: the documentation says it requires python 2, is it possible to install the version they recommend?

Comment: I have tried but have been not been successful.

Comment: Installing python 2 or running the program?

Comment: Can you, in Python with xlwings, open a new workbook and paste the data, then run the UDF on that data, before importing back into Python as a new pd.DataFrame?  That is quite easy to do with xlwings, provided that the function can be called easily.